# How to call textual function in javascript / jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, function

For example:

```html
<input id="#me" type="button" callme="doAction()"/>
    
<script>
     var result = callFunction( $("#me").attr('callme') );       /// ?????????
</script>
```

Comment: What do your callFunction does? Are you expecting to pass a string?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var callMe = $("#me").attr("callme");
    var result = eval(callMe);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the attribute `callme` is the name (identifier) of a function just use

```html
<input id="#me" type="button" callme="doAction"/>
```

```js
(window[$("#me").attr('callme')] || function() {})();
```

so you can avoid using an expensive `eval()`.

Comment: I like this but, I get this error: (f)(); f is not a function ?? the function exists...

Comment: Oops, sorry. Try this
(window[$("#me").attr('callme')] || function() {})();

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to not include the function in your HTML markup. It is almost always better to separate your markup from your scripting.

Instead consider adding it to your dom object using

```
$('#me').data('callme', function(){...});
```

or

```
$('#me').data('callme', doAction);
```

and calling it using

```
$('#me').data('callme')()
```

or a little safer

```
($('#me').data('callme')||jQuery.noop)()
```

See the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for more details on the data function.

Comment: I get this error: (f||jQuery.noop)(); f is not a function ?? the function exists...

Comment: `jQuery.noop()` is in jQuery version 1.4+

Comment: `jQuery.noop` can be replaced with `function(){}` if you need to
or you could assign it yourself somewhere with `jQuery.noop = function(){};`

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this is the solution:

```
<script>
setTimeout( $("#me").attr('callme'), 0 );
</script>
```

But how to get the returned value??